# How do I attach a local ssd to a Datalab instance?

Tags: google-cloud-datalab

I would like to attach a local SSD to a Datalab instance. The [documentation page](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/disks/local-ssd) describes how to do so for a Compute Engine instance, but those steps do not seem to work for Datalab instances specifically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried creating a new SSD and attaching it to the instance? After creating the Datalab instance, go to the cloud console -> Compute Engine -> Disks, create the SSD with your preferred configuration, then go to Compute Engine -> VM Instances and edit the Datalab instance to add the disk.

You can then follow the instructions to [format the disk and mount it](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/disks/local-ssd#formatandmount).